# Pytest and coverage: why do coverage results vary with directory structure?

Tags: django, python-2.7, pytest, coverage.py

I have a working test suite using Pytest on a fairly large django project. Problem is I am unable to achieve proper results using coverage, and I am wondering if it may be because of the projects directory structure.

Consider the following sample of the directory tree:

```
.
├── apps
│   ├── api
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   ├── tests
│   │   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   │   └── views
│   │   │       ├── __init__.py
│   │   │       └── test_tickets.py
│   │   └── views
│   │       ├── __init__.py
│   │       ├── tickets.py
│   ├── support
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   ├── tests
│   │   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   │   └── utils
│   │   │       ├── __init__.py
│   │   │       ├── test_management_commands.py
│   │   ├── utils
│   │   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   │   ├── management_commands.py
```

And a sample output of the coverage report:

```
coverage run --source apps/ -m py.test apps/
coverage report

Name                                        Stmts   Miss  Cover
---------------------------------------------------------------
apps/api/views/tickets.py                      42     18    57%
apps/support/utils/management_commands.py     135    100    26%
```

Looking at the html report I can see many statements executed by the tests are not considered covered, even though they should be. I believe this coverage data to be incomplete, it seems to only be considering imports, definitions, and docstrings as covered.

Unable to determine why the coverage appeared incorrect, I tried running a single test module, with positive results:

```
coverage run --source apps/support/utils/management_commands.py -m py.test apps/support/tests/utils/test_management_commands.py
coverage report

Name                                        Stmts   Miss  Cover
---------------------------------------------------------------
apps/support/utils/management_commands.py     135     68    50%
```

This is more accurate, the HTML report shows the statement I have tests for are indicated as covered this time. Unable to figure out why running a single test module yields accurate results, I modified the directory structure by moving the tests under a single parent folder.

```
.
├── apps
│   ├── api
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   └── views
│   │       ├── __init__.py
│   │       ├── tickets.py
│   ├── support
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   ├── utils
│   │   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   │   ├── management_commands.py
├── tests
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── api
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   └── views
│   │       ├── __init__.py
│   │       └── test_tickets.py
│   ├── support
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   ├── utils
│   │   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   │   ├── test_management_commands.py
```

Re-running coverage with this directory structure yields more accurate results:

```
coverage run --source apps/ -m py.test tests/
coverage report

Name                                        Stmts   Miss  Cover
---------------------------------------------------------------
apps/api/views/tickets.py                      42      0   100%
apps/support/utils/management_commands.py     135     68    50%
```

Can anyone explain why running coverage with py.test was yielding in complete coverage under the original directory structure? Was the directory structure actually the problem or am I missing something else here?

Additional info:

```
# pytest.ini
[pytest]
addopts = --nomigrations
markers =
    slowtest: mark a test as being slow
    integration: mark a test as being an integration test

INSTALLED_APPS += ('django_coverage', )
TEST_DISCOVER_PATTERN = 'test_*'
COVERAGE_MODULE_EXCLUDES = [
    'settings',
    'urls$',
    'locale$',
    'tests$',
    'django',
    'migrations',
    'compressor',
    'templates?$',
    'fixtures$',
    'static$',
]
ROOT_PATH = os.path.abspath('%s/' % os.path.dirname(__file__))
```

The .coveragerc

```
[run]
source = apps
omit =
     apps/*/templates?/*
     apps/*/migrations/*
     apps/*/factories/*
     apps/*/tests/*
[html]
directory = coverage
```

Module versions (some may be unrelated):

```
pytest==2.9.0
pytest-cov==2.2.1
pytest-django==2.9.1
django-coverage==1.2.4
coverage==4.0.3
```

Comment: It looks like you may have the pytest-cov plugin enabled, and you are running py.test under coverage.  You should pick one technique or the other.  Using both together is bound to cause some confusion.

Comment: Are the tests that would cover the code in question actually run with the old directory structure? You can easily check that by modifying them so that they should fail and see if the assertion errors pop up in the test result.

Comment: Thanks for the replies, I have removed pytest-cov and verified it is not listed as a plugin when running pytest. However, coverage is still yielding incomplete results with the old directory structure. I also added some assertions that would fail, and re-running the tests yielded failures indicating the tests were actually being run. I will continue digging to see why this is, and any further suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I see I'm a little late to the party (3-year-old question with no accepted answer yet), but since I've just had this same [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58477931/why-are-most-of-my-projects-django-files-missing-from-the-pytest-coverage-repor/58553418#58553418) with a seemingly obvious [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58553418/1224827): `coverage` will only report on code that is actually run. So if your tests don't call a bit of code and it doesn't get run during normal loading of the application, `coverage` will not show a report for that code. Code that doesn't run does not cause bugs :)