# Why are most of my project's Django files missing from the PyTest Coverage report?

Tags: django, pytest, coverage.py, pytest-django, pytest-cov

I'm running `pytest-cov` and `pytest-django` using `tox`. I have a very simple `tox.ini` file with limited `omit` files. The problem is when I run `pytest` using `tox -e unit`, I get a limited Coverage report:

```
---------- coverage: platform darwin, python 3.7.4-final-0 -----------
Name                                           Stmts   Miss  Cover   Missing
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
components/__init__.py                             0      0   100%
components/client/__init__.py                      0      0   100%
components/client/admin.py                        27      0   100%
components/client/factories.py                    57      0   100%
components/client/models.py                       62      0   100%
components/controller/__init__.py                  0      0   100%
components/controller/admin.py                    62      6    90%   96-97, 109-110, 122-123
components/controller/management/__init__.py       0      0   100%
components/controller/models.py                  107      6    94%   19, 31, 54, 92, 105, 132
components/personal/__init__.py                    0      0   100%
components/personal/admin.py                      24      0   100%
components/personal/factories.py                  39      0   100%
components/personal/models.py                     81     16    80%   23, 36, 49, 62, 72, 75-76, 92-104
server/__init__.py                                 3      0   100%
server/celery.py                                  10      1    90%   30
server/config/__init__.py                          1      0   100%
server/settings.py                                52      0   100%
server/test.py                                    56     33    41%   16-19, 43, 48-49, 63-88, 94-105, 112-115
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
TOTAL                                            589     62    89%
```

All of my Django apps under `components` have many files that should be covered in the report, including `apps`, `serializers`, `signals`, `urls`, and `views` (the standard Django structure). Anyone have any idea what I'm missing? Everything I've got in the `tox.ini` seems to follow pretty much exactly what I've read in the various documentation for `pytest`, `pytest-django`,  `pytest-cov`, and `coverage`, but I must be missing something important!

`tox.ini`

```
[tox]
; The only reason we'd want to `sdist` is if we distributed this as a Python package in PyPI, so let's skip it:
skipsdist = True
envlist =
    {py37}-django{2}
    lint
skip_missing_interpreters = true

[testenv]
whitelist_externals = *
passenv = *
deps = -rrequirements-test.txt
commands = {[testenv:unit]commands}

[testenv:unit]
deps = {[testenv]deps}
commands = pytest {posargs:--cov=project-name}


[pytest]
DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE = server.settings
python_files = tests.py test_*.py *_tests.py
addopts =
    -v -s
    --color=yes
    --cov
    --cov-append
    --cov-report=term-missing
    --cov-config=tox.ini


[coverage:report]
show_missing = True
omit =
    */usr/*
    */.tox/*py
    */.virtualenvs/*
    */migrations/*
    */tests/*

[report]
omit =
    */usr/*
    */.tox/*
    */migrations/*
    */tests/*
```

Answer (score 4):

The answer seems quite trivial and obvious, but amazingly, it was quite difficult to come by. `coverage` will only report on code that is actually run. So if your tests don't call a bit of code and it doesn't get run during normal loading of the application, `coverage` will not show a report for that code. Code that doesn't run does not cause bugs :)

Answer (score 0):

As per the Coverage.py documentation:

> Only importable files (ones at the root of the tree, or in directories with a `__init__.py` file) will be considered. [Source](https://coverage.readthedocs.io/en/latest/source.html#source)

So you either have to make sure that the code is executed by your tests OR ensure that the directories where your code resides have `__init__.py`.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem too,and i changed the tox.ini like below and it works!

```
[pytest]
DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE = server.settings
python_files = tests.py test_*.py *_tests.py
addopts =
    -v -s
    --color=yes
    --cov=.
    --cov-append
    --cov-report=term-missing
    --cov-config=tox.ini
```

--cov=. means the entire project.
Remember to put tox.ini in the root directory of the project.

I don't know how did you run the Django app and the pytest command,
here is mine

```
coverage run manage.py runserver --noreload 0.0.0.0:8000 --settings=djangoproject.settings.local &

pytest
 
pgrep -f 9000 | xargs kill -2

coverage report

coverage html
```